# Can I transfer pre-installed apps from a device with a broken screen to a different one?

Tags: applications, backup

So I have an Ematic Funtab Mini running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) OS that now has a broken screen that is totally unresponsive. I also have a Craig 7" TouchScreen Tablet running Google Android 4.0, Flash 11.1. I can't access anything on the Funtab, or find any place that can replace the screen. It came with a bunch of kids apps including a full versions of Angry Birds, Cut the rope, Where's My Water and a few more. Is it possible to transfer those apps (and maybe the data, but particularly the apps) to the Craig? I didn't have the Funtab long enough to use Google Play to back up the apps. So, any help in finding out if it's possible to transfer the apps would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it really the apps you want to back up, or the data? You can just install any apps from Google Play onto your new device, even apps you paid for.

Comment: It's really the apps. The Funtab came with a bunch of kids apps including a full versions of Angry Birds, Cut the rope, Where's My Water and a few more. We didn't have the tablet but a few says before the screen cracked! If GooglePlay was even on it i didn't have time to back up to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't transfer system apps (that is, the apps that came preinstalled) to another device or back them up. The apps will be built into the Funtab's ROM (or *system image*), and even if you could extract the files, they almost certainly will have copy protection to stop you using them on a different device.

To make an analogy, imagine you bought a PC and it came with PowerDVD. Now imagine you were to break the PC and buy a completely different one from a different manufacturer. You wouldn't have an install disk for PowerDVD, and the old installation would have copy protection so you can only use it on that specific model of PC. If you wanted to install PowerDVD on your new PC, you'd have to go out and buy it. Preinstalled apps on Android are no different.

If you'd downloaded Angry Birds from Google Play (or most other marketplaces), you'd be able to install it on any device with your account. You wouldn't need to back it up: Google would know that you'd bought it, so they would let you download it again for free. Preinstalled apps don't work that way, though.